# Awk - Sum fields of specific lines based on susbtring

Tags: awk, sum, field, line

i have a file that looks like :

```
100001001 0 130
100001001 0 610
100001001 0 210
100001001 0 100
100001001 1  80
100001002 0 300
100001002 0 200
100001002 0 100
100001003 0 200
100001003 0 100
100001004 1  50
```

I would like to sum the third field for each same 1st field, and exclude the lines from this total that contain 1 in the second field, with an output like the following :

```
100001001 1050
100001002  600
100001003  300
```

The command i ve worked so far doesnt seem to work for some reason, can someone assist me?

```
awk ' $2 != 1 { sum[$1] += $3 }'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one-liner should help:

```
 awk '$2!=1{a[$1]+=$3}END{for(x in a)print x, a[x]}' file
```

The problem in your codes is, you didn't print the output after doing sum in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to this tested one:

```
awk '{ if (NR==1) {sum=0} else if (lastid!=$1) {printf("%s %s\n", lastid, sum); sum=0} if ($2!=1) {sum+=$3} lastid=$1} END{if (sum>0) print lastid, sum}' afile
```

It is assumed that first column is sorted.

Comment: Awk is not C. What you're currently doing with awk is like if you were working with C++ but only used procedural programming and just the subset of C++ constructs that only exist in C - it's missing the point/benefits of the language. See [@Kent's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36767662/1745001) and read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you'd like to learn how to use awk idiomatically.

Comment: @EdMorton  Waou! Thank you! It is not an idiomatic version, but it has been tested. I will read the book with care.

Comment: @EdMorton If you refer specifically to associatives arrays, I took care to not use them in my answer, to highlight that the `END` part is not necessary (if the first column ids are sorted). I found it more funny to compute the sum and display the values while reading the lines.

Comment: No, it wasn't that, printing when the key changes and in END is a perfectly reasonable and common approach with sorted keys (the END part IS necessary, btw - your code only produces the expected output because the last input line has $2==1). It's mainly not using awks default variable values and built-in `<condition>{<action>}` structure and instead writing `{ if (<condition>){<action>} }` like you'd have to in C. Your approach would be written in idiomatic awk as `awk '$2==1{next} lastid!=$1{ if (NR>1) print lastid, sum; lastid=$1; sum=0} {sum+=$3} END{print lastid, sum}' file`

Comment: @EdMorton gloups! the answer will be edited, to fix the bug. As you guessed it was only tested with the example. I will test this new idiomatic version also. thx! I already used a variable without initializing it to see what's happening but I usually don't do it because I simply don't know these default values. I may have more questions after having read the book.

Comment: FYI all awk scalar variables are of type "numeric string" and are initialized to the value "zero or null". They become numbers or strings later based on the context in which they are first used. All arrays contain numeric string contents but all array indices are **strings** (no ambiguity there and do not think `a[3]=foo` means that `a[]` has numeric indices as it doesn't - the `3` will be converted to `"3"` in that context). Yes, reading that book is the best starting point - saves years of head scratching!